# Unknown host even though Avahi is installed and running

Tags: networking, 16.04, avahi

I'm running a 16.04 server on an old iMac. My network connectivity is up and running and avahi-daemon is installed, but I cannot ssh to my machine without explicitly using the ip.
In spite of all this, the server is still showing up as a shared machine in the finder of my mac.

On my client machine (Fangorn is the server):

```
mathsaey@Anduin $ ssh Fangorn.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname fangorn.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
mathsaey@Anduin $ ping Fangorn.local
ping: cannot resolve Fangorn.local: Unknown host
```

When I use the ip of the machine everything works fine:

```
mathsaey@Anduin $ ssh 10.0.10.1
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64)
```

Avahi is installed and running on the server:

```
mathsaey@Fangorn:~$ ps -ef | grep -i avahi
avahi     2117     1  0 15:44 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [Fangorn.local]
avahi     2121  2117  0 15:44 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
mathsaey  2198  1970  0 15:56 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i avahi
```

[As mentioned, the server does show up as a shared machine in the finder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyWVW.png)

I'm a complete novice to networking and setting up servers, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that just installing `libnss-mdns` is not enough, you need some configuration to actually use it.

Particularly, the host line of the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file should have `mdns4` in there somewhere.

My host line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for anybody who may run into the same issue:

`hosts:          files mdns4 [NOTFOUND=return] dns`

Comment: `sudo apt install libness-mdns` with host name `hosts: files mymachines mdns4 [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname` worked form me